# What alternatives are there to numpy on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy

What alternatives can you recommend to numpy to use on the Google App Engine?

Specifically I'm interested in matrix manipulations on large matrices.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve with numpy?  add some details to your question.

Comment: Done, but if anyone is aware of new libraries being developed to fill the void because GAE does not support numpy would be helpful.

Comment: Are you hoping for something as fast as numpy?  If so, you're probably out of luck until someone harnesses parallelism instead of optimized machine instructions, since App Engine doesn't support installable native code libraries.  If you're just looking for something with a convenient interface, you might want to say so.

Comment: Well fast as possible is a given considering the GAE script time limits, however a convenient interface would be a start.

Comment: Euclid supports 4x4 matrices, but I have a feeling you're talking much bigger: http://pyeuclid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/euclid.py

Comment: begin to star [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=190) if you haven't done it yet. Maybe in a couple of years..

Comment: Python natively supports large integers. Are the operations you're doing simple enough (eg, dot product etc) that you could simply implement them yourself?

Comment: You could also consider implementing calculation portions in Java; I've spoken with people who have move the heavy calculation portions of apps to a Java version (of the same app) with very good results.  Should be much easier since you can now specify a version for a particular queue to run tasks on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: As [remarked by Matthew Simoneau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741443/7920) and [by @petr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490723/what-alternatives-are-there-to-numpy-on-google-app-engine/5492162#comment16874505_5492162), the Python 2.7 runtime on GAE now includes Numpy among it's [libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

When this question was originally asked and answered, the old answer was the following.

**Old answer**: GAE only supports native python code, so any modules written in C are out of the question. You could look around for native python modules with the functionality you need, but they will be slow. e.g., [here](http://www.techlists.org/archives/programming/pythonlist/2007-06/msg01840.shtml). Amazon AWS or Rackspace might be a better fit if you need custom software installed, but its more expensive. Another option would be to have your app on GAE and do computation somewhere else via an API like [picloud](http://www.picloud.com/).

Comment: is it possible to call the picloud functions from GAE ? wouldn't picloud be considered as external libraries out of the native python 2.5 ?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but if the picloud client installation is pure python, it should not be a problem. picloud is a startup, they'll try to accomodate you.

Comment: GAE python27 runtime now includes numpy out-of-the-box

Answer (score 12):

The Python 2.7 runtime [includes NumPy 1.6.1](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

Comment: .. and more specific link - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27