# Looking for a pure-python NxMxZ matrix library

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deal with an arbitrary-sized (NxMxZ) 3D matrix in Python, about 50MB of floating point numbers in total. I need to do simple as-efficient-as-possible sum and average calculations across axes and diagonals, but nothing very fancy, and the matrix is dense.

Anyone know if such a library exists? I've found a number of "3D matrix" libraries for python, but they're all for 3D graphics, and are limited to, e.g. 4x4x4 matrices. Normally I'd use Numpy, but I'm on Google AppEngine, and can't use a library that requires C extensions.

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't use C extensions? Isn't Python written in C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What alternatives are there to numpy on Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490723/what-alternatives-are-there-to-numpy-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just [announced](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/4bde29d8e6dc0842?pli=1) a trusted tester program for Python 2.7 support, which includes NumPy. You might want to consider signing up for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ndim:             # from 3D array to flat array
    def __init__(self,x,y,z,d):
        self.dimensions=[x,y,z]
        self.numdimensions=d
        self.gridsize=x*y*z
    def getcellindex(self, location):
        cindex = 0
        cdrop = self.gridsize
        for index in xrange(self.numdimensions):
            cdrop /= self.dimensions[index]
            cindex += cdrop * location[index]
        return cindex
    def getlocation(self, cellindex):
        res = []
        for size in reversed(self.dimensions):
            res.append(cellindex % size)
            cellindex /= size
        return res[::-1]
""" how to use ndim class
n=ndim(4,4,5,3)
print n.getcellindex((0,0,0))
print n.getcellindex((0,0,1))
print n.getcellindex((0,1,0))
print n.getcellindex((1,0,0))

print n.getlocation(20)
print n.getlocation(5)
print n.getlocation(1)
print n.getlocation(0)
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ndim:             # from nD array to flat array
    def __init__(self,arr_dim):
        self.dimensions=arr_dim
        print "***dimensions***"
        print self.dimensions
        self.numdimensions=len(arr_dim) 
        print "***numdimension***"
        print self.numdimensions
        self.gridsize=reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, arr_dim)
        print self.gridsize
    def getcellindex(self, location):
        cindex = 0
        cdrop = self.gridsize
        for index in xrange(self.numdimensions):
            cdrop /= self.dimensions[index]
            cindex += cdrop * location[index]
        return cindex
    def getlocation(self, cellindex):
        res = []
        for size in reversed(self.dimensions):
            res.append(cellindex % size)
            cellindex /= size
        return res[::-1]

# how to use ndim class
arr_dim = [3,3,2,2]
n=ndim(arr_dim)
print "*****n.getcellindex((0,0,0,0))"
print n.getcellindex((0,0,0,0))
print "*****n.getcellindex((0,0,1,1))"
print n.getcellindex((0,0,1,1))
print "*****n.getcellindex((0,1,0,0))"
print n.getcellindex((0,1,0,0))
print "*****n.getcellindex((2,2,1,1))"
print n.getcellindex((2,2,1,1))
print
print "*****n.getlocation(0) "
print n.getlocation(0)
print "*****n.getlocation(3) "
print n.getlocation(3)
print "*****n.getlocation(4) "
print n.getlocation(4)
print "*****n.getlocation(35) "
print n.getlocation(35)
```

Comment: This is almost the same answer as above, without any explaination. Please explain the imortant point of your answer and why it differs from other answers.